# Homebrew installed formulae file

Tags: homebrew

I'm looking for a solution to save all installed formulae, similar to what `package.json` does for npm, or any other package manager with it's config file.

Is this possible with homebrew?

Comment: It seems this is roughly answered in [List of all apps installed using Homebrew](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/101092).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this:

```
for p in $(brew list); do brew info $p; done > brewconfig.txt
```

If you wanted something a little more complete and legible:

```
#!/bin/bash
brew list > brew-packages.txt
for p in $(brew list); do
   brew list $p > brew-$p-files.txt
   brew info $p > brew-$p-config.txt
done
```

which gives this

```
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff      381  4 Mar 13:02 brew-wget-files.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff      617  4 Mar 13:02 brew-wget-config.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff      496  4 Mar 13:02 brew-zlib-files.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff      377  4 Mar 13:02 brew-zlib-config.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff     3849  4 Mar 13:02 brew-zeromq-files.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff      455  4 Mar 13:02 brew-zeromq-config.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff     4292  4 Mar 13:02 brew-xz-files.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff      309  4 Mar 13:02 brew-xz-config.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was actually doing something similar, but I thought there might be a easier way.

Answer (score 0):

There is! `brew tap homebrew/brewdler` and `brew brewdle dump`. See `brew brewdle help` for details.